# How Do You Group Data in a CollectionView

Tags: maui

I am trying to present grouped data in a CollectionView.  I tried following the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping.  I could not get this to work in my project.  So I created a brand new project and did a straight copy and paste from the link above, and it still does not display any data.

The only thing not shown in the link above is establishing the databinding, which I do with Xaml like this:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
                IsGrouped="True" x:Name="GroupTestView">
```

And code like this from a button click handler:

```
//code that populates the Animals property is copied from the documentation page

//do the data binding
GroupTestView.BindingContext = Animals;
```

I have verified in the debugger that the Animals property is populated with data.  However the page does not display any data.  Is this working right now?

Comment: I'm sure your View Models have implemented INotifiyPropertyChanged and all that? Your {Binding Animals} variable is assuming your ViewModel is properly set up. If you are using the code behind, I think you should use GroupTestView.ItemsSource = Animals;

Comment: the BindingContext and the ItemsSource are two different things, and you have them set to the same value.  The BindingContext should be an instance of the class that contains the ItemsSource

Comment: Thank you DaWiseguy, you were right, using ItemsSource instead of BindingContext worked.  I'm not sure why that is, given that I've been using BindingContext on all my other views, but I will happily go digging into this deeper.  Thank you!

Comment: @StevePeschka - Jason explained why your BIndingContext didn't work. What is the class that **contains** the property Animals? BindingContext must be an instance of the containing **class**, not the property itself.

Comment: Thanks ToolmakerSteve, I was having some trouble parsing what Jason was saying but I get it now.  I think the difference perhaps is that in my other views for ItemsSource I just have been using {Binding} without a class identifier.  In this case I was trying to follow the documentation so I used it as they had written.  Thanks all for the help and explanations.